# Many-to-many Model A is not associated to Model B using Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to set up many to many associations with Sequelize. I have two models, User and Artist. A user can follow many artists, and an artist can be a part of many users following lists:

User:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    userUID: DataTypes.STRING,
    username: DataTypes.STRING,
    mod: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {});
  User.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    User.belongsToMany(models.Artist, { through: models.UserArtist, foreignKey: 'userID', otherKey: 'artistID' });
  };
  return User;
};
```

Artist:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Artist = sequelize.define('Artist', {
    followers: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    imageURL: DataTypes.STRING,
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    artistUID: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {});
  Artist.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    Artist.belongsToMany(models.User, { through: models.UserArtist, foreignKey: 'artistID', otherKey: 'userID' });
  };
  return Artist;
};
```

I have a join table:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const UserArtist = sequelize.define('UserArtist', {
    userID: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    artistID: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {});
  UserArtist.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
  };
  return UserArtist;
};
```

But when I try and Eager Load UserArtist, I get an error

```
Artist.findAll({
    where: { artistUID: req.params.id },
    include: [
        { model: UserArtist }
    ]
```

> SequelizeEagerLoadingError: UserArtist is not associated to Artist!

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: It should be `model: User` in `include` instead of `UserArtist`

Comment: @Emma thanks! I think that worked, I included `model: User` and now when I print out in console, the `UserArtist` is found within the `User` model results. Is this how it should behave?

Comment: Could you post what you get?